# Jetty 5.1.x start after 10 minutes or after "real local connexion"

Tags: java, debian, jetty, osgi

I work on a very old system : OSGi Framework with Jetty.
Java command is launch inside a screen with -DmS parameters.

At the end, console give me this :

```
osgi> Sep 14, 2021 9:17:43 AM org.mortbay.http.HttpServer doStart
INFO: Version Jetty/5.1.x
Sep 14, 2021 9:28:32 AM org.mortbay.util.Container start
INFO: Started org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.Servlet25Handler@90832e
Sep 14, 2021 9:28:32 AM org.mortbay.util.Container start
INFO: Started HttpContext[/,/]
Sep 14, 2021 9:28:32 AM org.mortbay.util.FileResource <clinit>
INFO: Checking Resource aliases
Sep 14, 2021 9:28:33 AM org.mortbay.http.SocketListener start
INFO: Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:[port]
Sep 14, 2021 9:28:33 AM org.mortbay.util.Container start
INFO: Started org.mortbay.http.HttpServer@142bece
Experimental:  JNI_OnLoad called.
```

And :

```
ss

Framework is launched.

id      State       Bundle
0       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.2.R34x_v20080826-1230
1       ACTIVE      javax.servlet_2.4.0.v200806031604
2       ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.logging_1.1.1.v20080605-1935
3       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_1.1.0.v20080425
4       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.0.100.v20080427-0830
5       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.1.200.v20071203
6       ACTIVE      org.mortbay.jetty_5.1.14.v200806031611
7       ACTIVE      org.apache.log4j_1.2.13.v200806030600
                    Fragments=14
8       ACTIVE      Jamod_0.0.0
9       ACTIVE      org.openscada.opc.dcom_0.5.0
10      ACTIVE      Comm Linux RXTX Bundle_0.0.0
11      ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.io_1.4.0
12      ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.fileupload_1.2.1
13      ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.lang3_3.1.0
14      RESOLVED    InterpreterLog4JProperties_0.0.0
                    Master=7
15      ACTIVE      EmailManager_1.0.0
16      ACTIVE      Interpreter_1.0.0
17      ACTIVE      InterpreterServlet_1.0.0
```

But during 10 minutes, I have only this :

```
osgi> Sep 14, 2021 10:16:06 AM org.mortbay.http.HttpServer doStart
INFO: Version Jetty/5.1.x
ss

Framework is launched.

id      State       Bundle
0       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.2.R34x_v20080826-1230
1       ACTIVE      javax.servlet_2.4.0.v200806031604
2       ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.logging_1.1.1.v20080605-1935
3       STARTING    org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_1.1.0.v20080425
4       RESOLVED    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.0.100.v20080427-0830
5       RESOLVED    org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.1.200.v20071203
6       RESOLVED    org.mortbay.jetty_5.1.14.v200806031611
7       RESOLVED    org.apache.log4j_1.2.13.v200806030600
                    Fragments=14
8       RESOLVED    Jamod_0.0.0
9       RESOLVED    org.openscada.opc.dcom_0.5.0
10      RESOLVED    Comm Linux RXTX Bundle_0.0.0
11      RESOLVED    org.apache.commons.io_1.4.0
12      RESOLVED    org.apache.commons.fileupload_1.2.1
13      RESOLVED    org.apache.commons.lang3_3.1.0
14      RESOLVED    InterpreterLog4JProperties_0.0.0
                    Master=7
15      RESOLVED    EmailManager_1.0.0
16      RESOLVED    Interpreter_1.0.0
17      RESOLVED    InterpreterServlet_1.0.0
```

I don't want to modify java code (too old, too long), I just want to start it correctly...

Finally someone have notice that if I plug a screen and a keyboard on this server, and log in, jetty start at once ?
(Whereas this doesn't work with ssh log in...?)

I think in my case, the simplest way (not perfect and clean I agree), would be to simulate a "real log in" (but I don't understand what is the difference between "real/local" log in and ssh log in).

Comment: I think I will create another question about the last part, because I can't find solutions on the jetty/osgi/java part...

Answer (score 0):

Jetty 5.1.14 was EOL (End of Life) back in the year 2009 - https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.php#version-table

There has literally been over 1 million commits on Jetty over the past 12 years (I just checked)

For success with this old of a version of Jetty ...

- You MUST run it with Java 1.4 (ONLY) and nothing newer.  Newer JVMs have various things disabled that Jetty of that era require to run.  (You could eke out Java 1.5, but only if you have SSL/TLS disabled, and don't use that specific version of OSGi, which only supported Java 1.2)
- You MUST run it on an OS that wasn't upgraded in the past 12 years.  Newer OSs have updated to support the feature-set of newer JVMs and dropped support for the quirks of older JVMs and will not run older JVMs reliably.
- You MUST NOT use SSL (it's impossible for you to use it now).  SSL/TLS has evolved extremely rapidly since 2009, and you have a featureset in the Java 1.4 JVM that is 100% not supported on modern web browsers. This means even if you turned it on, your modern browser has a minimum TLS 1.2 and a Cipher Suite that Java 1.4 doesn't even support on it's high end / non-export configurations.

So in short, you cannot upgrade Jetty (your choice), so you cannot upgrade the JVM (consequence of your first choice), and you cannot upgrade the OS (if you expect to run Java 1.4) for success.

If you have upgraded your JVM or your OS you have basically screwed yourself.  I cannot even find a docker image with that old of a OS or JVM for you to limp along with.

Comment: More info : exept the issue of very slow start-up, everything works fine ! I use Java 1.6 and change the OS for Debian 9. This application is obviously not on wan...

Comment: For Java 1.6 support you have to upgrade both Jetty and OSGi, go back to Java 1.4 and you'll have less issues.